# How can I set layout options for my table in, MS word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, latex, layout

MS Word 2013 has several options for setting the layout of a picture (in-line, top and bottom, ...) (fix position, move with text). But, about tables it lacks such options.

When I write something in Latex, tables (like the figures) are some entities starting with '\begin{}' and ending in '\end' and latex manages their location, but I am very hand-limited in handling the position of tables in MS Word.

What is your suggestion to me so that I can become able to have such options (fixing the position of a table, moving with text or ... ... ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more positioning options for Tables, but they are different from the ones you can use with Pictures etc.

For example, if you click a table's selection box (e.g. top left corner on a system set up for LTR script) you can drag a table to another point int he page. Then, if you right-click on the selection box and select Table Properties... you should see that text wrapping is set to "Around", and a Positioning... button is enabled that lets you specify a few more things related to positioning. (Or you can access these things via the Ribbon's Table Tools->Layout->Table->Properties).

Comment: Great! but why it only has around? In the around case, I can go and set not to 'move with text'. But if I deselect around I don't have that choice. I need 1- not Around 2- not 'move with text'. Does it provide me with such choice?

Comment: Moreover, I have another (let's say) problem when I fix my table position. How can I fix its caption? In the case of picture, I group it with its caption and then set the grouped item to be fixed on the page. The first idea is to put the caption in a border-less table and then fix that table!

Comment: @hossayn: I only really tried to answer the basic question about whether there were other layout options for tables. Beyond that, you may be better off asking another question. "why" questions are difficult for anyone except the original software authors to answer (an advantage of TeX/LaTeX is the original literate documentation by Knuth). As for the caption, Word does not have a formal link between the caption and the related object. Tables & text boxes are possible ways to keep them together, but you may be better off avoiding even those.